# Получить все элементы ListView

Tags: android, listview, java

Доброго времени суток! Я пытаюсь написать приложение под Android, и у меня возникла следующая проблема. У меня есть ListView, которое заполнено элементами. В каждом элементе есть чекбокс. Я хочу по нажатию кнопки отметить все чекбоксы. Я пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);

for(int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) { 
    View view = ((CheckBox)list.getChildAt(i);     
    view.findViewById(R.id.myCheckbox)).setChecked(true);
}
```

Всего элементов в ListView семь, на экране умещается 4. Так вот, когда i становится больше 3, то при попытке обратиться к `list.getChildAt(i)` я получаю `NullPointerException`. Насколько я понимаю, с помощью `getChildAt` я могу обратиться только к тем элементам, которые видны на экране. А как мне обратиться вообще ко всем элементам в ListView вне зависимости от того, отображается он на экране или нет? Можно ли как-то получить все 'tktvtyns ListView? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понял вас. Смотрите. Допустим, я имею список каких-то моделей, который хочу отобразить в ListView. Я их привязываю к ListView, они отображаются на экране, но не все умещаются, и нужно прокручивать. Пока что все здорово. Но в каждом элементе ListView есть элемент CheckBox. Также у меня есть кнопка. Я хочу, чтобы когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то все чекбоксы отмечались галкой. Когда нажимаю во второй раз нажимаю - чтоб галка снималась. Для этого я пытаюсь перебрать все элементы в ListView и найти в них чекбокс. Но получается обратиться только к первым четырем элементам. Что я делаю не так

Comment: Ничего не читал, но по коду вижу - лажа, первое, потому что, кроме установки флажка, надо обновлять значение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зайдем с другой стороны, если у тебя есть чекбоксы, вероятнее всего, у тебя кастомный адаптер, тогда - в нем, на чекбокс повешай листенер, который будет менять состояние объекта, потом на кнопку ВЫДЕЛИТЬ ВСЕ повешай акшн, который пробежится по всем твоим объектам и выставит им флаг выделенной галочки, а потом адаптеру сделать нотифайДатаСетЧендж.

Если все, что написано, непонятно, учи матчасть. =)

Comment: А если, допустим, мне нужно по долгому нажатии на элемент у всех элементов сделать чекбокс видимым (а до этого они были не видимыми), как это сделать

Answer (score 2):

Залил на гитхаб:
https://github.com/JenyaKirmiza/TestListView

Я сделал по тупому.

Вот кастомный адаптер:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.zip.CheckedInputStream;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

ArrayList< Integer> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private ViewHolder viewHolder;
private Integer wp;
private Context c;

    public void setSelectedAll() {
        this.isSelectedAll = !isSelectedAll;
    }

    /*--- a simple View Holder class ---*/
static class ViewHolder {
    public CheckBox checkBox;
    public TextView textView;
}
private boolean isSelectedAll=false;

/*--- Context and all weapons of specified class are passed here ---*/

public ListAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> items, Context c) {
    this.items =  items;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();

}

@Override
public Integer getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /*--- initialize our Weapon Object ---*/
    wp = items.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        /*--- no View is available. Inflate our list item layout and init the Views we need ---*/
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (isSelectedAll)
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    else
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

    viewHolder.textView.setText(wp+"");
    return convertView;
}
   }
```

Вот в активности:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            arrayList.add(i);

        listAdapter=new ListAdapter(arrayList, getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectAll);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listAdapter.setSelectedAll();
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Это так, по-быстрому. А вообще я бы делал, как Gorets посоветовал. Листенер вешал на чекбокс в getView, а сам listener создавал в кастомном адаптере.

Обрати внимание на использование паттерна ViewHolder. Еще советую все изображения в лист вьюхах грузить в фоне.

Answer (score 1):

Через адаптер их получать надо.

```
list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Comment: Так я получу мою модель, привязанную к элементу, находящемуся в ListViiew. A мне хотелось бы получить сам элемент из ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Так их и создаётся ровно столько, сколько помещается на экране. В дальнейшем уже созданные `View` просто используются повторно.

А то, что вы хотите сделать, реализуется выставлением у `ListView` нужного режима выбора:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

С последующим вызовом

```
listView.setItemChecked(itemPosition, true);
```

И да, чтобы вся эта магия работала правильно, не забудьте реализовать интерфейс `Checkable` у `View`, который представляет собой элемент `ListView`.

Comment: Я, наверное, что-то не понял из вашего ответа, но дело в том, что я хочу отмечать не сам View, а CheckBox, находящийся в нем. Причем я хочу это делать не только руками (вручную он отмечается), а еще и програмно. То есть по нажатию на кнопку "выделить все".

Comment: Так без проблем. Отмечайте, что вам нужно. Для этого и нужно имплементировать `Checkable`. А вообще, почитайте про используемые в `ListView` оптимизации. А ещё лучше, и даже проще — посмотрите исходники `AdapterView`. Многое станет понятнее.

Comment: Я, наверное, какие-то глупые вопросы задаю, но я вообще ничего не понимаю. Мне выше советовали использовать 

    list.getAdapter().getItem(position)

и это почти работает. Я получаю все элементы, могу найти в них чекбокс. Но потом я почему-то не могу этот чекбокс отметить. То есть я делаю так: 

    for(int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
        View item = adapter.getView(1, null, list);
        CheckBox ch = ((CheckBox)item.findViewById(R.id.myCheckbox));
     ch.setChecked(true);              
    } 

Код выполняется без ошибок. Но сами чекбоксы не отмечаются и остаются без галок.

Comment: Потому, что вышеприведённым кодом вы не существующие элементы получаете, а создаёте новые `View`, которые в дальнейшем нигде не используете. В общем, последуйте моему совету и почитайте документацию, там всё весьма подробно разжёвано. И в сорцы загляните. И не надо ничего изобретать.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием это сделал, если бы понимал, о чем речь. Я правда не могу понять, почему мне нужно отмечать сами элементы, если мне надо отметить только чекбокс, находящийся в элементе (а если бы у меня элемент имел сложную структуру и содержал несколько чекбоксов, из которых нужно было бы отметить  только некоторые, то как тогда?)

Comment: Я смотрю, вы, несмотря на непонимание, упорно не желаете читать документацию. Боюсь, в таком случае, я вам больше ничем помочь не могу.